# Weblogic jdbcdrivers.xml entry for jtds

Tags: jdbc, weblogic, weblogic11g, jtds

This is an entry for setting up JDBC for `sqljdbc4.jar`

```
<Driver
  Database="MS SQL Server"
  Vendor="Microsoft"
  Type="Type 4"
  DatabaseVersion="2005 and later"
  ForXA="false"
  ClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
  URLHelperClassname="weblogic.jdbc.utils.MSSQL2005JDBC4DriverURLHelper"
  TestSql="SELECT 1">
      <Attribute Name="DbmsName" Required="true" InURL="true"/>
      <Attribute Name="DbmsHost" Required="true" InURL="true"/>
      <Attribute Name="DbmsPort" Required="true" InURL="true" DefaultValue="1433"/>
      <Attribute Name="DbmsUsername" Required="true" InURL="false"/>
      <Attribute Name="DbmsPassword" Required="true" InURL="false"/>
</Driver>
```

Whats is the appropriate `URLHelperClassname` entry for `jTDS` ? **So that the correct connect string is formed.**

Currently its missing out... `:jtds` from the connection string where I have to add it manually.

Comment: Have you followed the full example here: http://zeosaho.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-install-jdbc-driver-on-oracle.html What errors are you seeing?

Comment: @castling I want the entries for jtds so the correct url string comes. So that I dont have to manually set it